# How to obtain the orientaion from the north for set of lines?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

I have a set of lines represented by the two endpoints. I would like to obtain the orientation from the north (i.e. the angle between the line and the meridian traversing the westernmost extremity of the line (clockwise from North)). For example, the angle between `b` and `u`.

The issue:
I have tried this [solution](https://www.redcrab-software.com/en/Calculator/Angles-Of-Lines), however, the `acos()`  does not produce the right angle, especially, in the case of lines/vectors other than `u` (see image, from `A` to `B`). Additionally, I can't use the slope formula because `tan(90°)`  would be problematic in  `R`.

The slope formula:
$\phi = \tan^{-1}\dfrac{m_1 - m_2}{1+m_1 m_2} $

The function I wrote in R and examples of performance:

```
    Orientation <- function(x1, y1, x2, y2){ 
        
        #first line scalar product
        a<-c(sort(c(x1,x2),decreasing = T)[1]-sort(c(x1,x2),decreasing = T)[2],
                 sort(c(y1,y2),decreasing = T)[1]-sort(c(y1,y2),decreasing = T)[2])
        #second line scalar product
        b<-c(0,180)
        
        #magnitude of the vector
        a_mag<-sqrt(a[1]^2+a[2]^2)
        b_mag<-sqrt(b[1]^2+b[2]^2)
        
        a_b<-a[1]*b[1]+a[2]*b[2]
        
        angle_between_two_lines<- acos(a_b/(a_mag*b_mag))*180/pi 
        
        return(angle_between_two_lines)
    }
```

**Example lines:**

[image]

**Results**

```
> #u
> Orientation(3,3,5,5)
[1] 45
> #v
> Orientation(8,5,11,5)
[1] 90
> #w 
> Orientation(8,3,10,1)
[1] 45
> #a 
> Orientation(1,1,1,3)
[1] 0
```

For line `w`, it should be $135°$ from the north, but it doesn't work!

Comment: Before returning the value $angle\_between\_two\_lines$, you can check whether $\left(y_1 - y_2\right) \gt 0$ and if that is the case, add $90^0$ to it.

Comment: It worked like a charm thanks :) You can put it as an answer, if you want!

Comment: You can simplify things a lot if you take as vectors $a=(0,1)$ and $b=(x_2-x_1,y_2-y_1)$.

Comment: Use function atan2.